# AngularJS: Access promise callback outside a async method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
function graphreport(agentList) {

    var b;
    var self = this;

    agentList.getAgentsList().then(function (data) {
        self.agents = data.data.users;
        console.log(data.data.users.length);
        b = data.data.users.length;
    });

    console.log(b);
}
```

First console.log will return the value. Second console log will return `undefined`. How do get the variable outside a method? BTW, I'm resolving a promise in the method.

Comment: Please show all relevant code

Comment: you cant use it outside the scope of then.. it is asynchronous.. your outer console.log is probably called before the inner one

Comment: What's in agentList?

Comment: agentList is my service name where I have made API calls.

Comment: I need to use the variable outside scope to generate a graph/chart. Any alternative to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You could achieve this by using [promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) or a callback. But you will not be able to make it like you tried to in just one linear procedure. Get aware of async JavaScript bevhaviors. Here is an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s6rzshkv/).

#### With promises

```
function graphreport(agentList) {

    var b;
    var self = this;
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var promise = deferred.promise;

    agentList.getAgentsList().then(function (data) {
        self.agents = data.data.users;
        console.log(data.data.users.length);
        b = data.data.users.length;
        deferred.resolve(data.data.users.length);
    });

    promise.then(function (b) {
        console.log(b);
    });
}
```

#### With callback function

```
function graphreport(agentList) {

    var self = this;

    agentList.getAgentsList().then(function (data) {
        self.agents = data.data.users;
        console.log(data.data.users.length);
        myCallack(data.data.users.length);
    });

    function myCallack(b) {
      console.log(b);
    }
}
```

### With co & yield like in this [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/18nktdq3/).

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($timeout, $q) {

   co(function *() {
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     var promise = deferred.promise;

     function someAsync() {
        $timeout(function () {
              deferred.resolve('test');
        }, 250);
     }

     someAsync();
     var b = yield promise;
     console.log(b);
   });
});
```

Comment: @punithgowda does it work for you? You maybe going to mark the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

Since, your var `b` only gets resolved after promise resolution, you have to retrieve it asynchronously. One of the ways is  you can use `callback` as shown below. So when promise is resolved `b` gets returned with your `callback` function.

```js
function graphreport(agentList, callback) {
    var b;
    var self = this;
    agentList.getAgentsList()
            .then(function (data) {
                self.agents = data.data.users;
                console.log(data.data.users.length);
                b = data.data.users.length;
                //return the callback method
                return callback(null, b);
            });
}

graphreport(list, function(err, b){
  if(!err){
   console.log(b);
   }
});
```